# XSLT apply templates in different order of xml reading

Tags: xml, xslt

I am new to this, so please bear with me...

If we have the following xml fragment:

```
<docXML>
<PARRAFO orden='1' tipo='parrafo'>
    <dato>
      <etiqueta>Título</etiqueta>
      <tipo>TextBox</tipo>
      <valor>¿Cuándo solicitar el consejo genético?</valor>
      <longitud>1500</longitud>
      <comentario></comentario>
      <enlace></enlace>
      <target_enlace>I</target_enlace>
    </dato>
    <dato>
      <etiqueta>Texto</etiqueta>
      <tipo>Resumen</tipo>
      <valor>Resumen text</valor>
      <longitud>8000</longitud>
      <comentario></comentario>
      <enlace></enlace>
      <target_enlace></target_enlace>
    </dato>
    <dato>
      <etiqueta>Imagen</etiqueta>
      <tipo>TextBox</tipo>
      <valor>http://url/Imagenes/7D2BE6480CF4486CA288A75932606181.jpg</valor>
      <longitud>1500</longitud>
      <comentario></comentario>
      <enlace></enlace>
      <target_enlace>I</target_enlace>
    </dato>
  </PARRAFO>
  <PARRAFO orden='1' tipo='parrafo'>
    <dato>
      <etiqueta>Título</etiqueta>
      <tipo>TextBox</tipo>
      <valor>TextBox text</valor>
      <longitud>1500</longitud>
      <comentario></comentario>
      <enlace></enlace>
      <target_enlace>I</target_enlace>
    </dato>
    <dato>
      <etiqueta>Texto</etiqueta>
      <tipo>Resumen</tipo>
      <valor>Resumen text</valor>
      <longitud>8000</longitud>
      <comentario></comentario>
      <enlace></enlace>
      <target_enlace></target_enlace>
    </dato>
  </PARRAFO>
</docXML>
```

.. I am going to apply templates to each section depending on the value of the label "etiqueta" per node "dato" in "PARRAFO" by using the following XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:msxsl="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xsl" exclude-result-prefixes="msxsl">

  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:variable name="xml-doc-parrafo" select="documentoXML/PARRAFO"/>
   <!-- PARRAFOS -->
    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="count($xml-doc-parrafo)>0">
        <div class="seccion_1">
          <xsl:for-each select="$xml-doc-parrafo">
            <xsl:choose>
              <xsl:when test="self::node()[@tipo = 'parrafo']">
                <div class="parrafo">
                  <xsl:for-each select="self::node()[@tipo = 'parrafo']/dato">
                    <xsl:variable name="dato" select="self::node()[@tipo = 'parrafo']/dato"/>
                    <xsl:variable name="nextdato" select="following::dato[1]/@etiqueta"/>

                    <xsl:choose>
                      <xsl:when test="etiqueta = 'Título'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="imprimeTituloParrafo">
                          <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:when>
                      <xsl:when test="etiqueta = 'Subtitulo'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="imprimeSubtituloParrafo">
                          <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:when>

                      <xsl:when test="etiqueta = 'Imagen'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="imprimeImagenParrafo">
                          <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:when>

                      <xsl:when test="etiqueta = 'Pie Imagen'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="imprimePieImagenParrafo">
                          <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:when>

                      <xsl:when test="etiqueta = 'Texto'">
                        <xsl:call-template name="imprimeTextoParrafo">
                          <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                          <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                        </xsl:call-template>
                      </xsl:when>

                    <xsl:when test="etiqueta = 'Pie Parrafo'">
                      <xsl:call-template name="imprimePieParrafo">
                        <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                        <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
                      </xsl:call-template>
                    </xsl:when>

                    </xsl:choose>
                  </xsl:for-each>
                </div>
              </xsl:when>
            </xsl:choose>
          </xsl:for-each>
        </div>
      </xsl:when>
      <!-- si no hay resultados -->
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <br></br>
        <p style="text-align:center;">El documento no contiene datos.</p>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
 </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="imprimeTituloParrafo">
    <xsl:param name="etiqueta"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="valor"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="longitud"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="enlace"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="target_enlace"></xsl:param>

    <h2 class="titulo">
      <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="string-length($enlace) > 0">
            <xsl:call-template name="imprimeEnlace">
              <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
              <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
            </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$valor"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </h2>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="imprimeSubtituloParrafo">
    <xsl:param name="etiqueta"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="valor"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="longitud"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="enlace"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="target_enlace"></xsl:param>

    <h3 class="subtitulo">
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="string-length($enlace) > 0">
          <xsl:call-template name="imprimeEnlace">
            <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:otherwise>
          <xsl:value-of select="$valor"/>
        </xsl:otherwise>
      </xsl:choose>
    </h3>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="imprimeTextoParrafo">
    <xsl:param name="etiqueta"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="valor"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="longitud"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="enlace"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="target_enlace"></xsl:param>

    <div class="texto">
      <p class="texto">
        <xsl:copy-of select="$valor/node()"/>
      </p>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="imprimeImagenParrafo">
    <xsl:param name="etiqueta"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="valor"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="longitud"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="comentario"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="enlace"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="target_enlace"></xsl:param>

    <xsl:choose>
      <xsl:when test="string-length($enlace) = 0">
        <xsl:call-template name="imprimeImagen">
          <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
          <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
        </xsl:call-template>        
      </xsl:when>
      <xsl:otherwise>
        <a>
          <xsl:choose>
            <xsl:when test="$target_enlace/node() = 'E'">
              <xsl:attribute name="target">
                <xsl:text>_blank</xsl:text>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
            <xsl:when test="$target_enlace/node() = 'I'">
              <xsl:attribute name="target">
                <xsl:text>_self</xsl:text>
              </xsl:attribute>
            </xsl:when>
          </xsl:choose>
          <xsl:attribute name="href">
            <xsl:value-of select="$enlace"/>
          </xsl:attribute>

          <xsl:call-template name="imprimeImagen">
            <xsl:with-param name="etiqueta" select="etiqueta"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="valor" select="valor"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="longitud" select="longitud"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="comentario" select="comentario"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="enlace" select="enlace"></xsl:with-param>
            <xsl:with-param name="target_enlace" select="target_enlace"></xsl:with-param>
          </xsl:call-template>

        </a>
      </xsl:otherwise>
    </xsl:choose>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template name="imprimeImagen">
    <xsl:param name="etiqueta"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="valor"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="longitud"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="comentario"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="enlace"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="target_enlace"></xsl:param>
    <div class="imagen_pie">
      <img>
        <xsl:attribute name="src">
          <xsl:value-of select="$valor"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
        <xsl:attribute name="alt">
          <xsl:value-of select="$comentario"/>
        </xsl:attribute>
      </img>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>


  <xsl:template name="imprimeEnlace">
    <xsl:param name="valor"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="longitud"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="comentario"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="enlace"></xsl:param>
    <xsl:param name="target_enlace"></xsl:param>
    <a>
      <xsl:choose>
        <xsl:when test="$target_enlace/node() = 'E'">
          <xsl:attribute name="target">
            <xsl:text>_blank</xsl:text>
          </xsl:attribute>
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$target_enlace/node() = 'I'">
        </xsl:when>
        <xsl:when test="$target_enlace/node() = 'D'">
        </xsl:when>
      </xsl:choose>
      <xsl:attribute name="href">
        <xsl:value-of select="enlace"/>
      </xsl:attribute>
      <xsl:value-of select="$valor"/>
    </a>
  </xsl:template>

 .... 

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I need to first apply the template image (if exists in this "PARRAFO") "Imagen" just before the text "Texto"

Now apply the template text first and then the image because it is before the text node before the image as shown in xml

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry, but it is not very clear -- could you, please, provide a shorter (the shortest possible) example that demonstrates your problem? Using english for the markup will not hurt, either. :)

Comment: See the solution in my answer. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are attempting to write the XML in a 'procedural' style, when XML is best written in a 'declarative' style.  These are known as 'pull' and 'push' processing.  Here's an example using your data that may help:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" exclude-result-prefixes="xs" xmlns:xd="http://www.oxygenxml.com/ns/doc/xsl" version="1.0">
  <xsl:output method="html" encoding="iso-8859-1"/>

  <xsl:template match="/">
    <rootNode>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="docXML/PARRAFO[@tipo='parrafo']"/>
    </rootNode>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="PARRAFO[@tipo='parrafo']">
    <div class="parrafo">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dato[etiqueta='Imagen']"/>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="dato[etiqueta='Texto']"/>
    </div>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dato[etiqueta='Imagen']">
    <image></image>
    <!-- processing -->
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="dato[etiqueta='Texto']">
    <text></text>
    <!-- processing -->
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1):

I completely don't understand the provided XML document and the details of the question (sorry, haven't learnt Italian yet :(  ), but **here is a small example how to process XML elements not in their document order**.

**This transformation:**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0"
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
 <xsl:output omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>

 <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
  <xsl:copy>
   <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
  </xsl:copy>
 </xsl:template>

 <xsl:template match="/*">
   <nums>
    <odd>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
    </odd>
    <even>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="*[position() mod 2 = 1]"/>
    </even>
   </nums>
 </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**when applied on this XML document**:

```
<nums>
  <num>01</num>
  <num>02</num>
  <num>03</num>
  <num>04</num>
  <num>05</num>
  <num>06</num>
  <num>07</num>
  <num>08</num>
  <num>09</num>
  <num>010</num>
</nums>
```

**processes and outputs first the odd-numbered `<num>` elements, then the even-numbered ones**:

```
<nums>
    <odd>
        <num>01</num>
        <num>03</num>
        <num>05</num>
        <num>07</num>
        <num>09</num>
    </odd>
    <even>
        <num>01</num>
        <num>03</num>
        <num>05</num>
        <num>07</num>
        <num>09</num>
    </even>
</nums>
```

**The lesson from this example:** Non-document-order processing can easily be achieved by specifying the desired nodesets to be processed, in corresponding `<xsl:apply-templates>` instructions -- in their `select` attribute.